# On Windows, can I prevent LibreOffice from prompting for document recovery when it launches or I open a file?

Tags: libreoffice

I basically never want to use the feature. How to? There's another question here that answers how to disable it in Linux via a command-line option in .bashrc, but I don't think that can be done in Windows?

Edit: Additional information:

- I am on Windows 10
- No Recovery.xcu anywhere on my C drive.
- even if I discard recovery data, then the next time I open the same file there is no recovery prompt. But when I shutdown Windows without shutting down LibreOffice first, then I get the prompt the next time I open the file.

Answer (score 3):

#### Can I prevent LibreOffice from prompting for document recovery?

> when it launches or I open a file?

**To disable when launching a LibreOffice program**

Start LibreOffice with the `--norestore` command line option:

1. Right click on the "LibreOffice" Writer start menu entry.

   [image]
2. Click "Properties".

   [image]
3. Add `--norestore` to the end of the "Target" entry.
4. Click "OK".
5. Repeat steps 1-4 for each of the programs in the LibreOffice suite.

**To disable when opening a file**

Uncheck the "Save AutoRecovery information every:" option:

1. Start "LibreOffice".
2. Menu "Tools" > "Options".
3. Expand "Load/Save".
4. Select "General".
5. Uncheck "Save AutoRecovery information every:".

   [image]
6. Click OK.
7. Close "LibreOffice".

Now you can open files.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, I've already disabled that Autorecovery checkbox in the options, I still get prompted with autorecovery info

Comment: Search `C:\Users\<username>\AppData` and subdirectories for `Recovery.xcu`. Delete it and try again.

Comment: No such file anywhere on my C drive. I'm on Windows 10 if that matters. BTW, it's happening to me even if I discard recovery data, then the next time I open the same file there is no recovery prompt. But when I shutdown Windows without shutting down LibreOffice first, then I get the prompt the next time I open the file.

Comment: Then don't shutdown without closing LibreOffice!

Comment: Unchecking the _"Save AutoRecovery information every:"_ doesn't prevent the dialog on next launch after crash.